# Database connection error (local server to hostgator server)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am uploading my wordpress website to hostgator, I am getting this error. Pl help.

Error establishing a database connection. 
I am following the entire procedue. Dont understand this problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Login to your Hostgator account. Follow their database connection sample. Sometimes the SERVER is not always "localhost".